# Can a company print the wrong Net. Weight on a product?

Tags: canada, ontario

Are companies allowed to use old packaging (900g) on their new product which is (650g)?

Here's the story.

The product is a pita bread. My dad started buying this brand since it weighs more and costs less only to find out after weighing that the product uses the wrong package.

I called them and they said: "Yeah we had some of the old packages so we used that, what's the big deal?"

Is this allowed in Ontario?

Comment: Does he want to ask for 28% of his money back?

Comment: I think you're looking for the [Consumer Packaging and Labeling Act](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-38/); you may also be interested in Ontario's [Ministry of Agriculture, Food, and Rural Affairs](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/food/inspection/meatinsp/m-i-p-r/foodlabelling.htm).

Comment: @phoog Thanks, I think that is the one.  I'm thinking how can they be stopped? Since they are still selling it and acting like it's not a big deal. I also noticed that even the qty says 10 even though it's only 5.

Comment: Perhaps [Consumer Protection Ontario](https://www.ontario.ca/page/consumer-protection-ontario) would be interested.

Comment: @phoog Especially since they are doing this intentional, not by accident. Such a mistake requires that you fix it as soon as you get aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the regime in Canada, but I'd bet that it's not that different from the United States, where this would almost certainly violate a variety of laws.

Most likely it would lead to liability under a consumer-protection laws forbidding deceptive sales practices. It's not really any different than selling someone a dozen eggs and then giving them eight eggs.

Comment: The packaging itself might not violate the law, but selling goods with that packaging without disclosing the misleading language on the packaging at the point of sale probably would violate the law. If there were a prominent sign on the display and at checkout saying "Oops! We ran of the the correct bags and your Pita Bread is actually 650g rather than 900g and has 5 loaves instead of 10.", with a similar notice to buyers at wholesale, liability could probably be avoided.